# Building MSI through NAnt Build

Tags: windows-installer, nant

I'm assigned the task of getting our MSI's building through NAnt. I will use NAntContrib or WiX if I "have" to, but the time given to me for this ticket doesn't afford me the luxury of researching new build techniques. This is my first time working with NAnt.

The current Solution we have is 80 projects, 6ish services (with their own MSI install projects), and a handful of websites.

The build script builds the solution first, then starts copying all the built libraries, files, zips, configs to their specific locations so deployment is straight forward. The only problem is it does not build any MSI files.

The Build box has Visual Studio installed on it. From quickly looking around the net I saw that if you have VS installed, then running deven.com can build the MSI files...

The Solution being built contains the Install projects for the services, but no MSI's are getting created. Is there a specific setting / command line argument I must pass in to get this done?

The XML that is building the solution is as follows.

$builtype is "/build"

```
<target name="BuildOnly" depends="ConfigureBuild">
  <if test="${property::exists('Distribution') and Distribution == 'True'}" >
    <call target="ConfigureBuild.Release"/> 
 </if> 

 <call target="StopServices"/> 
 <call target="CleanSUOFiles"/>
 <!--<call target="BuildEnterpriseLibrary" />-->
 <property name="build.dir" value="${directory::get-current-directory()}"/>

 <echo message="######### ${buildtype} ${StandardProjectTarget}"/>

 <exec program="${deven.com}" workingdir="${build.dir}" failonerror="true"  commandline="&quot;BC_HM.sln&quot; ${buildtype} ${StandardProjectTarget}"/>

 <call target="BuildSchematronFiles"/>
</target>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAnt is a build tool, it's not related in any way with installation packages. It builds projects, it doesn't generate files on its own. So you need a project which generates an MSI package.

This can be created in multiple ways:

- use a [Visual Studio setup project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx)
- use a free setup authoring tool like [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)
- use a [commercial setup authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) which supports NAnt

Please note that creating installation packages is not an easy task. So analyze all setup authoring tools before choosing one.

Comment: We're calling devenv.com to build the installer. yes not the best but given time constraints on my ticket I am not changing it. When we move to a better build box and get rid of Cruise Control it'll be better. But in the mean time, devenv isn't building a msi.

Comment: devenv.com builds Visual Studio projects, not installation packages. Installers aren't created automagically. You need to create a setup project and build it in order to get an installer. Do you have setup projects? Or are you building projects randomly hoping to generate an installer?

Comment: I already have my installer package, the scripts and everything setup for it. however, running my devenv.com through NANT does not build it. I think i have found a way around it, but need to see if it works in our environment.